# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `FirstName' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a fairly simple association between my registrations and contestants models.

```
class Contestant < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :registrations
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contestant
end
```

I'm attempting to reference the name of a contestant from my registration index page.

```
 <tbody>
  <% @registrations.each do |registration| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= registration.contestant.FirstName%></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Accessing the page yields

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `FirstName' for nil:NilClass):
```

I'm running Ruby-2.3.3-p222 with activerecord 4.2.6 (Rails 4.2.6). I'm also tried ruby-2.2.4-p230 and go the same result. The twist is I have a similar association between my users and roles. I'm able to make the call `<%= user.role.name %>` with no issue. I've mirrored my logic between the two and am at a loss as to why. Thank you all for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here, is that (99%) not all of `@registrations` has associated `contestant`, thus you're getting an error.

Two options:

1) Only display the `@registrations` with associated `contestants`:

```
@registrations.joins(:contestant).each...
```

2) Use `try` to avoid the error:

```
registration.contestant.try(:FirstName)
```

Comment: Ahh you're right! "registration.contestant.try(:FirstName)" is showing blank values. Which is confusing since I'm referencing the correct contestant ID. Another mystery to solve, but this sends me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: @EDPittore no probs. Just check `ids = @registrations.joins(:contestant).pluck('registrations.id')` `Registration.where(id: ids)` - this will be the list of those, who has `contestant`.